# Where do posts get the sidebar from?

Tags: php, categories, sidebar

I'm trying to add an if statement on the sidebars that are displays in POSTS. I want posts to show a specific sidebar if it's in category x and display a different sidebar if it's not in category x.

To do this, i'm trying to use the following code:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 'featured-listing' ) || ( in_category( 'listing-post' ) )) { ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
   <?php get_sidebar2(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I've tried editing both the single.php and page.php to no avail. I thought maybe that since i removed the get_sidebar from my child theme that Wordpress was falling back to the Twentytwelve sidebar, but after trying a few things out it seems this isn't the case.

So - the summarize; i've tried editing both single.php and page.php to try and display different sidebars based on the category that the post is assigned to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`get_sidebar()` accepts a parameter `$name`. Then will look for a file `sidebar-{$name}.php`.

So what you can do is:

```
get_sidebar( get_post_type() ); // search for sidebar-post.php or sidebar-page.php
```

or:

```
if ( in_category( array( 'featured-listing', 'listing-post' ) ) )
    get_sidebar( 'listing' ); // sidebar-listing.php
else
   get_sidebar();
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue, though, is that i cannot find which file is placing the sidebar in individual posts. If i can find that, i can do what needs to be done; but i cannot, for the life of me, find what file is placing the sidebar as per original post.

Comment: @NikkiMather Some themes are calling `get_sidebar()` in `footer.php` or `header.php`. Use an editor that can search in a whole directory.

Comment: The Twentytwelve theme (i'm using a child theme of that) doesn't have the sidebar in the footer.php or header.php files. This is really confusing.

Comment: In Twenty Twelve the function is called in `index.php` at the bottom.

Comment: I tried removing it from index.php too, however the sidebar is still there.

Comment: @NikkiMather If the sidebars are showing up on posts only, look for `get_sidebar()` in the `single.php` file in your template directory.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to define separate sidebar for :

1.post

2.and page

3.in post for category

Place below code in your `sidebar.php`

```
<?php
if( 'post' == get_post_type()){
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach( $categories as $category ){
        $sidebar_template[]='sidebar-'.$category->slug.'.php';
    }
    //search for template for category
    $cat_template = pathinfo( locate_template( $sidebar_template ) );
    if( !empty( $cat_template )){
        $cat_template_name=explode( '-', $cat_template['filename'] , 2);
        get_sidebar( $cat_template_name[1] );
    }
    else{
        get_sidebar( 'post' );
    }

}else{
    get_sidebar('page');
}
?>
```

and create

1.`sidebar-page.php` for page

2.`sidebar-post.php` for post

3.`sidebar-category_slug.php` for post category

what code does:

1.If `get_post_type` is equal to post then , I retrieve all categories for current post and test is their any sidebar template for category it.if yes then sidebar for category will call ( `sidebar-category_slug.php` )else sidebar for post will call ( `sidebar-post.php` ).

2.If `get_post_type` is equal to page then sidebar for page will call ( `sidebar-page.php` ).

**Note**: code drived only for assuming current condition.We can modify it for different levels for example if we want to separate sidebar template for sub category.